# Why does Kotlin use global functions like arrayOf

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin. I find this to be a weird practice.

With the case of `arrayOf` / `mutableListOf`, the instinct is to try a *construct* one of these types using a constructor, i.e. `new Array<T>(...args)`. Or even a static factory method, like i.e. `LocalDateTime.of(...)`.

Why wasn't `new Array<T>()` used, or at least a scoped function, i.e. `Array.of`. Don't these methods also clutter the global scope?

Comment: JRE doesn’t have a global scope, it will always be wrapped in a class.

Comment: Yes, when compiled. I'm talking about the global scope in Kotlin. There are a host of things, that aren't scoped to a form of class / namespace, lying around in there.

Comment: There is no global scope - everything is in a package. Some packages are imported by default (like java.lang is in Java) but that doesn't put them in a global scope.

Answer (score 2):

`arrayOf` and `mutableListOf` are not in "global scope" (that's not even something that exists). They're in the `kotlin` and `kotlin.collections` packages, respectively.

It just so happens that `kotlin.*` and `kotlin.collections.*` are default imports of any kotlin file, so you don't have to make that import yourself. See [Default Imports](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports).

This is similar to Java where `java.lang.*` is imported by default and you don't need to specify it.

Also, you can't "construct" arrayOf and mutableListOf because they're not types; they're methods - and the fact the they start with a lowercase letter is the standard way to indicate that - types start with uppercase letters.

Kotlin allows methods at package level outside a class (although when compiled for the JVM, they will be inside a class), but that's not very different from an `import static` in Java with which you can access a static method from a class without the classname as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kotlin does not use the `new` keyword.
2. It makes it clear if the Array is Mutable or not.
3. There are javascript and native libraries that will map the call to other implementations.

Comment: Point 2 doesn't make sense. MutableArray.of is clearly a mutable array.

Comment: @Tobiq Doesn't Kotlin have `arrayOf` and `mutableArrayOf`?

Comment: @Tobiq with point 3, the other libs don't have an Array class.  Actually , I would have hoped for the [...] shorthand like Groovy uses.  JetBrains at least added that syntax to annotations a few versions ago.

Comment: There is no `mutableArrayOf`. Arrays are always mutable.

Comment: Perhaps not for arrays, but lists can be mutable or not, and share a common syntax, `listOf` and `mutableListOf`