# Why kotlin introduced "global notation" `listOf()` instead of static factory `List.of()` functions like Java?

Tags: kotlin, language-design

To create a collections in Kotlin we can use `listOf()/mapOf()/arrayOf()` factory functions. Those functions are defined in "global notation" compared to Java's static factory notation: `List<>.of()`.

In my opinion the Java's method of creating static collections is more intuitive and encourages better programming practices. Kotlin's way seems like a poor decision - names of functions are implicitly bound to the type they're returning. It contradicts the clarity point of Kotlin.

Why did Kotlin devs decide that it would be better to use `listOf()` `mutableListOf()` instead of `List.of()` and `MutableList.of()`?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072947/why-does-kotlin-use-global-functions-like-arrayof) already, but the answers aren't satisfactory - there is no info about WHY it exists in the form it does and what benefits it has over simple static factory-style methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From historical point of view, Kotlin was officially released and introduced that notation in 2016, before `List.of` arrived to Java in 2017 (with Java 9). So, there was no obvious *instead*.

Syntactically, `List.of` is implemented as a static function in `List` interface. Since there is no `static` keyword in Kotlin, it should be implemented as overloaded methods (for zero, one and several (`vararg`) parameters) of companion object. That will lead to `GETSTATIC` + `INVOKEVIRTUAL` calls instead of simple `INVOKESTATIC` (in global `listOf` case).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer as I'm not a Kotlin language designer.

`List` is an interface and as such should not relate to a specific implementation. If you add `of` to the interface then you need to pick some implementation for that list you're returning.

`listOf` is not a "special" function in any way it is just a coveninece thing that returns some implementation of a List, if you have some specific use-cases where you need another list implementation you can define your own `magicListOf` method which will look on the same "level" as `listOf`.